# ADO components fail on CommandTimeout, but seldom

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

We sometimes experience CommandTimeouts on relative simple DELETE queries.

They normally execute in a second or a few, but sometimes hit our 300 sec CommandTimeout.
So far we have seen it happen from 2 locations, where we send a lot of delete statements from loops. In one case a TADOStoredProc with parameters is used, in the other case a TADOCommand with a DELETE statement is used (no parameters). It does not happen in a predictable fashion, in two executions of the same code the result can vary. The exception happens rarely, so far we have gotten past it by re-running the program.

What could be the cause of these timeout?
What would the best solution be? Currently we are considering trying async execution and resending the command on timeout.

Comment: One common reason for command timeout is a lost connection.

Comment: Which Delphi version?  ISTR that a long time ago there was a problem with setting the time-out on ADO objects due to a coding omission in ADODB.

Comment: Your delete could be blocked by another long running query.

Comment: There might be a deadlock on the SQL (google that). try using isolated transactions (via `ADOConnection.BeginTrans/CommitTrans`). for multiple delete operations prefer `IN ()` statement, rather than executing delete in a loop. make sure you have PK/index on those ids...

Comment: @MartynA it is Delphi 2007. I'm pretty sure the timeout is set, at least with the stored proc I saw the program hang for almost exactly 5 minutes before excepting.

Comment: Ah, OK, what I was thinking of was much earlier than that, D5 I now see. @Kobik: I was wondering about a deadlock; maybe try putting a long WAITFOR in a deletion and see if that smokes it - or rather the other transaction - out?

Comment: @kobik, for deletion prefer DML array (where it's possible) ;-) That's a very fast beast and you will avoid compilation of a possibly long `IN ()` query.

Comment: In `Oracle` I have seen problems with `DELETE` sentences on tables that were frequently updated or if the necessary indexes were not created or refreshed. Not sure about the incidence of those problems in `SQL Server`.

Comment: @TLama, Does TADOCommand (ADO) even supports array DML? another option would be a temp table of ids and delete via join (or IN).

Comment: @kobik, I don't think so (here you can apply my note *where it's possible* :-) In this case I would prefer a parameterized loop with a prepared query inside a transaction, since building a long query (think about thousands of records) would be a bit overhead in my view.

Comment: @Kobik:  Well, this works fine for me against Sql Server:  AdoCommand1.CommandText := 'create table Table1(ID int identity)'; AdoCommand1.Execute; but I haven't tried anything else DDL-wise.  OTOH, regular contributor Jerry Dodge has a project, I believe, to recreate a whole lot of server objects and I imagine that uses DDL.